# Is there any way to cast void* to SEL

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm using obj-c runtime to fetch objects types & values from NSInvocation. And I don't know how to do what the title says.

This is how I retrieve info from NSInvocation
argValue supposed to be void*, specified index is SEL-typed argument.

```
[invocation getArgument:argValue atIndex:argIndex];
```

So how to cast `SEL sel = (???)argValue;`?

Comment: Have you tried `(SEL)argValue`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH, thanks for answer
Found:
`SEL value = nil; [invocation getArgument:&value atIndex:index];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow code.

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(anInvocation.selector));
  NSLog(@"%@", anInvocation);
}
```